# how to get rid of html in jsoup and only extract html table content?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

So I'm trying to access the table in this website http://www.engin.umich.edu/htbin/wwwhostinfo?detail=0&display=all&sort=open and trying to make it into an Elements object. I only need the first and fourth columns . So I'm using jsoup and doing this :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.engin.umich.edu/htbin/wwwhostinfo?detail=0&display=all&sort=open").get();
        Elements buildings = doc.select("td:eq(0),td:eq(3)");
```

This should select the first and fourth columns. It is doing that but with all the html data as well 
I need to skip all the initial stuff in the webpage "The following report ... ". And I only need the two columns - Building and Open so that I can simply initialize extra variables and assign the number of open computers in a building to it and finally use Toast or something similar to display the number of open computers in a building on the screen.

Currently I'm using a TextView to show data and its showing me all the html data I don't want as well.

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(""+buildings);
        setContentView(tv);
```

Can Individual values be extracted from Elements ?

in short: How to extract only building names and No. of Open computers by skipping ALL other data and assign them to their own variables?

Any ideas on how to do this?.

Thanks in Advance - a.v.

Comment: you have any idea of web scrapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the [JSOUP Cleaner & Whitelist](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) for that task.

Just define what shall not be removed and you're good to go!